# how to set the selected option value as null or undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I am adding the role list as search criteria and want user should be able to clear this search. For this, I am providing the empty option, but it is setting the search binding to an empty string. I want to know is there way to fix the binding to undefined when user select particular option? 
e.g., in this case when user select '' empty option binding value should be null or undefined.

The problem is search will show all the result if the selected role is set to null or undefined if it is set to empty string then it will try to search role matching empty string, and nothing appears.

```
<body class="fix-sidebar" ng-controller="tempctrl">
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="sort('role')">Role</th>
        <td>
          <select 
            ng-options="role as role for role in rolesList" 
            ng-model="search.role">
              <option></option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: could you share the code where you set the search binding to null or undefined?

Comment: That html code is incomplete or incorrect (missing tags, etc)